# resize function only works in one dimension

Tags: javascript, onload, onresize

I have a resize function that keeps the main div resized in a consistent ratio. I originally had it resizing according to window width which worked fine (the 1st condition in the function). Then I added a second condition so that if the window is too short it resizes according to the height.  This function works correctly with onload.

onresize works for width both when the window is made narrower or wider, but the height condition only works when the window is made shorter . . . if the window is then dragged taller the onresize event doesn't seem to trigger, I have to manually reload the page for the function to resize.

```
<script>  
function contentResizeHeight() {
    var contentBG = document.getElementById("content");
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var newHeight = Math.round(contentBG.offsetWidth * .6);

    if ( windowHeight > newHeight ){
        contentBG.style.height = newHeight + "px";
    }

    if ( windowHeight < newHeight ){
        var newerWidth = windowHeight * 1.666666666666666666;
        var newerHeight = Math.round(newerWidth * .6);

        contentBG.style.height = newerHeight + "px";
        contentBG.style.width = newerWidth + "px";
    }
};
</script>
```

The #content div is covered by a background image. So the idea is to keep the image aspect ration the same.

```
div#content{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width:1024px;
    max-width:1600px;
    min-height:614px;
    max-height:960px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

I call the function in the body tag

```
<body onload="contentResizeHeight()" onresize="contentResizeHeight()">
```

Comment: What's `#contentBG` and how its height is defined?

Comment: #contentBG is a div whose height is set by the width of the container. Maybe this fiddle shows the issue - resize the window narrower and wider and the height changes.  Resize the window shorter and it gets narrower, but if you then drag the window taller it doesn't change. http://jsfiddle.net/n8b03xab/

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0mc9bLn/) showing the values in the console, please study it carefully, you'll find an error in the logic.

Comment: Thanks, I had been logging all the variables already.  While they illustrate the end result, they don't really help me find the logic error.  What only logging in one condition at a time shows me is that sizing the window (narrow-wider) logs in both directions. Logging the second condition - resizing (shorter-taller) only logs while the window is getting shorter, i.e., as the window gets taller this condition is no longer satisfied.

Comment: Check the log info on my fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/n8b03xab/2/ it shows that when heightening the window it reverts to condition 1.  So the second condition is not right.  Hmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Achieving this goal with a background image

If you're trying to achieve this with a background image, you can use the help of the CSS `background-size: contain;`. From Mozilla's site on the keyword [`contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

Using this logic you can pretty much just scale up each dimension as much as you want based on the window size, and let CSS do the rest of the work.

```
function contentResizeHeight() {
    var contentBG = document.getElementById("content"),
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        contentBG.style.height = windowHeight + "px";
        contentBG.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n8b03xab/8/) to see it in action.

#### When working with a plain div/no background image

This is more for anyone who happens to stumble across this answer looking for the same result as above, but with a plain `div` (maybe with a background color or something) and no help from CSS: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8b03xab/6/)

```
function contentResizeHeight() {
    var contentBG = document.getElementById("content"),
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
        contentHeight = contentBG.offsetHeight,
        contentWidth = contentBG.offsetWidth,
        newHeight = null,
        newWidth = null;

    if ( windowHeight > contentHeight ){
        // 40 is the buffer zone for increasing the windows width quickly
        if( contentWidth < windowWidth - 40 ){
            newWidth = contentHeight * 1.666666666666666666;

            if( newWidth >= windowWidth - 10 ){
                newHeight = Math.round(newWidth * .6);
            } else {
                newHeight = windowHeight;
            }

        } else {
            newHeight = Math.round(contentWidth * .6);
            newWidth = windowWidth - 4;
        }

    } else if ( windowHeight < contentHeight ){
        newHeight = windowHeight;
        newWidth = newHeight * 1.666666666666666666;
    }

    contentBG.style.height = newHeight + "px";
    contentBG.style.width = newWidth + "px";

}
```

This is just how I managed to get it working 95%, so if someone has a solution to the window width issue, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This is much better, at least it is somewhat fluid. There are some edge cases with this solution like first shorten the window, then widen the window where the sizing jumps around a lot, but it's close. I don't expect people to be resizing their window like crazy.  I'll keep looking at this.  FYI the real solution is a div with a background image, background-size:cover; this is so that the image is not distorted.

Comment: Here's a more representative test at http://rdiv.com/jsTest/ There is an issue with unload not sizing properly until you start to drag the window size. And you can see some of the jumpiness at times.

Comment: Ohhh ok, dealing with a background image is much easier. I'll add an update. You probably want to clarify that as well in your initial question as well.

Comment: @jim I've updated my post to account for a background image situation. Let me know if that's more what you were going trying for.

Comment: YEs. I am using background-size:cover and the revision to your answer does work. I don't know how to mark your revision as the correct answer.

Comment: Great :) To give points for a good answer, click the up arrow at the top of an answer. And to accept an answer as the one that worked for you, click the checkmark by the up and down arrows.

Comment: Sure, it's just that the checkmark goes next to your rather long and not working first answer, seems like your revision gets lost (and that's the money).

Comment: I've updated my answer because I think that's a good point. It should make more sense for anyone who happens to come upon this question.